# Why doesn't Dhall allow returning types from if expressions?

Tags: dhall

Dhall has functions that return types:

```
let f = \(b : Bool) -> Natural                   -- ok
```

And it has `if` expressions:

```
let f = \(b: Bool) -> if b == True then 1 else 0 -- ok
```

But the two features can't be used together:

```
-- Error: ❰if❱ branch is not a term 
let f= \(b : Bool) -> if b == True then Natural else Integer

in 3
```

Why?

At first I thought this was a trick to avoid having dependent types, but it seems Dhall does allow types to really depend on values when working with unions. The following compiles fine:

```
let MyBool = <T | F>

let myIf: MyBool -> Type = \(b: MyBool) ->
        merge
          { T = Bool
          , F = Natural
          }
          b
          
in 3
```

**UPDATE**

The [dhall standard](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/pull/1090) supports such if expressions now, as does [dhall-haskell](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-haskell/pull/2080), thanks @gabriel-gonzales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unintentional inconsistency in the language due to how it evolved, and the inconsistency can be fixed.

When the language was first released neither `if` nor `merge` could return a type.  Later on, unions and `merge` were updated to permit types in this pull request:

- [Allow record fields and union alternatives to be types](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/pull/91)

… but we haven't yet updated `if` expressions with a matching change.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I opened an issue for updating the standard: https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/pull/1090

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for fixing the standard :)